# Can't add device via http on FIWARE-IoTAgent

Tags: fiware

I'm learning about IoT and trying to use Fiware for a project and got stuck when trying run some commands while following the fiware-IoTAgent-Cplusplus deployment guide.

I could successfully run:
`curl -X GET http://172.17.0.4:8080/iot/about`

Sending the above command I got the following result:
`Welcome to IoTAgents  identifier:qa:8080  1.3.1 commit 124.g0b78609 in Sep 14 2016`

When I tried to run the following command it returns "pidfile not found             [FAILED]", so I must have missed some configuration
`service iotagent start protocol`

Any other requests returns 'The request is not well formed':

```
curl -X POST http://x.x.x.x:8080/iot/services \
-i \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Fiware-Service: service2" \
-H "Fiware-ServicePath: /srvpath2" \
-d '{"services": [{ "apikey": "apikey2", "token": "token2", "cbroker":           "http://127.0.0.1:1026", "entity_type": "thing", "resource": "/iot/d" }]}'
```

Any ideas of what can be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use an old version of the IoTAgents that is no longer supported. Please, try to use one of the new Node.js versions (e.g.: https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul)